# chrome extension after computer sleep has huge delay

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have google extension and in order to do some task I created:

`chrome.alarms.create("activateAlarm",{periodInMinutes: 1});`

And listener:

`chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener((alarm) => { //do something }`

What I noticed is when computer goes to sleep mode for longer period (probably more then 6 hours) and when I wake up computer my alarm stop working.
Actually it doesn't stop working completely, but it does not activate alarm in one minute as it should do.
But after some time, I don't know much time it needs but then alarm start to works correctly.

I set listener to listen about computer state:
`chrome.idle.onStateChanged.addListener(listener => { })` and it shows me when computer is in `active`, `locked` or `idle` state.

Also in period when alarm does not work I do check: `chrome.alarms.getAll()` and I can see that alarm is present: `name: "activateAlarm" periodInMinutes: 1 scheduledTime: 1630557806472.038`.

Does any one has similar problem.

Comment: Sounds like a bug so you can report it on https://crbug.com if it's not reported already.